# How to create connection for mdf files

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, connection-string

I am creating a Windows application with a local database.

Now I need to define a connection string for that local database in C#.

What is the connection string for local `.mdf` files in Winforms C#?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use SqlServeCe as a namespace and then give the following codings

```
     using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

      SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=D:\PROJECT\data\db.mdf;");
```

Comment: `.mdf` is the **full** SQL Server - not SQL Server Compact ..... so you need to use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (not `SqlCeConnection`). SQL Server CE database files are `.sdf` files

Comment: while given sqlconnection it shows an error I Think Sqlservece is correct for my code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:

- In your *Server Explorer* window right click on the database that
  you've created and select `Properties`.
- in the `Properties` window copy the value of the connection string
  property and paste it to your application.

It should be something like this:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=True
```

Just you need to add one extra `\` to it to work in c#:

```
string address = "Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=True";
```

You could also have a look at 
[The Connection Strings Reference.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<add name="YourDataBase" connectionstring="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;  AttachDbFilename=Path\YourDataFile.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True" />
```

Also you can visit connectionstring.Com as well for more.